# the order a finite group with elements with orders of $10$ and $6$

Tags: group-theory

Let $a,b$ be in a finite group $G$.
when $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, I could say the order of $G$ is the product of orders of $a$ and $b$.
However, when the order of $a$ is $10$ and the order of $b$ is $6$, their $\gcd(a,b)$ does not equal to $1$. In this case what can we say about the order of $G$?

Comment: make your question clear. If G is group of order 2.3.5=30, then taking an element a of order 2 and b of order 3, can you conclude that order of G is 2.3?

Answer (score 0):

With the information that you have provided you know that the order of the group is at least $30=lcm(10,6)$ because the order of every element has to be a divisor of the order of the group because of Lagrange's theorem. But as @Groups points out in his comment you need more information if you want to know the order of the group.